# Inherit From SQLAlchemy Joined Table Inheritance Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy

Python 3.6 and SQLAlchemy 1.2.

I have a package called `events` which defines `Match` as a type of `Event` and uses joined table inheritance to distinguish it from other types of `Event`. The other type of event is `Competition`, all events are one or the other:

```
class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_events'
    event_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_type_id = Column(String(50))  # 0 is Match, 1 is Competition

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': event_type_id}

class Match(Event):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_match_details'

    event_id = Column(Integer,
                      ForeignKey('tbl_events.event_id'),
                      primary_key=True)
    team_1 = Column(String(50))
    team_2 = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 0}
```

I'm using `Match` in another package which distinguishes multiple types of `Match` and relies on the `Match` object's attribs and methods to pull event info from the database but operates away from the database otherwise to that:

```
from events import Match

class BaseMatch(Match):
    # define common methods and attrs

class TennisMatch(BaseMatch):

    # do Tennis based stuff

class FootballMatch(BaseMatch):

    # do football based things
```

Any difference between `events.Match` and the classes that inherit from it only matter in this package and this package doesn't otherwise insert or update the database, only reads from it.

The issue I'm having is that attempting to instantiate an instance of any of the classes that inherits from `Match` results in a `NULL` value being passed into the query for the `event_type_id` field. This is the `WHERE` part of the query:

```
WHERE tbl_match_details.event_id = %s AND tbl_events.match_comp_id IN (NULL)
```

I can't simply give each class their own polymorphic identifier as those identifiers won't exist in the database.

I tried this:

```
class BaseMatch(Match):
    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return {'polymorphic_identity': 0}

class TennisMatch(BaseMatch):
    # do tennis stuff

class FootballMatch(BaseMatch):
    # do footy stuff
```

but importing the module, I get warnings like:

```
SAWarning: Reassigning polymorphic association for identity 0 from <Mapper at 0x7f80197f0550; Match> to <Mapper at 0x7f80197a9fd0; BaseModel>: Check for duplicate use of 0 as value for polymorphic_identity.
SAWarning: Reassigning polymorphic association for identity 0 from <Mapper at 0x7f80197a9fd0; BaseModel> to <Mapper at 0x7f800dfdf940; TennisMatch>: Check for duplicate use of 0 as value for polymorphic_identity.
```

I get one of those for each class that inherits from `Match` and when I attempt to instantiate any of the match types, I get an instance of the type last to have been associated with that polymorphic id.

I'd really appreciate a nudge in the right direction!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done to work around this - I'm not sure if it is 'right' but it has allowed me to move forward with what I'm doing and helped me to understand a bit more of the goings on under the hood.

I've created a factory methods on my Event, Competition and Match classes and a class attribute on Competition and Match that gives me access to each event type's event_type_id value:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_events'
    event_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_type_id = Column(String(50))  # 0 is Match, 1 is Competition

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': event_type_id}

    @classmethod
    def from_id(cls, id, session):
        mapper = inspect(cls).mapper
        mapper.polymorphic_map[cls.EVENT_TYPE_ID] = mapper
        mapper.polymorphic_identity = cls.EVENT_TYPE_ID

        return session.query(cls).filter_by(event_id=id).one()

class Match(Event):

    EVENT_TYPE_ID = 0

    __tablename__ = 'tbl_match_details'

    event_id = Column(Integer,
                      ForeignKey('tbl_events.event_id'),
                      primary_key=True)
    team_1 = Column(String(50))
    team_2 = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': EVENT_TYPE_ID}
```

This way, whenever classes that inherit from Match or Competition are instantiated using the factory methods, the polymorphic identity is forced to the identity defined on the parent class and the polymorphic map points that identity to the class that the factory is being called upon.

A disadvantage obvious to me is that this will only work when objects are instantiated through the factory methods. Fine in this case but maybe not for all.

Would appreciate any feedback on how I've gone about this and any pointers toward a cleaner solution.

Thanks